# How to protect against poison in ES Blades?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-blades

I see  things one can do against elemental damage- such as „ward“, but nothing against poison. Just began an abyss run and got wrecked by those obnoxious poison-skeevers...

Edit: Now that my alchemy laboratory finished, I can brew some weak potions to protect myself. Is this the only option?

Answer (score 1):

Below I list the things I found out. But If you’re looking for a single practical strategy, the **chitin shield** alone has so far (lvl 20) proven sufficient to protect me from almost all poison attacks.

### More Observations

As evidenced by the following icon and confirmed [here](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Elemental_Damage) poison is counted among the types of elemental damage.
[image]

Accordingly, the possibilities are more than I feared:

- Spell: Resist Elements
- Spell: Ward
- After building the Alchemist‘s Shop: specialised cordial
- Perk: Combat focus. Grants 9% resistance to any kind of damage, but only while using an ability.
- Chitin shields frequently and equipment offer huge block Boni against poison.